# Can't install VSIX extension file in Visual Studio Express 2013?

Tags: windows-8.1, themes, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio Express Web on Windows 8.1

I went to [this site](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe) and downloaded the extension for the VS theme editor for VS 2013.  However, when I double-click it it tries and fails to install.

I get this error:
[image]

Is it not possible to add this extension, or even edit themes easily, in VS Express?

Comment: Visual Express has never support extensions.  If a theme is considered an extension it would explain the error.  You can import/export your settings which determine certain visual charaistics in VS Express

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Visual Studio Express Editions don't support extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Extensibility).

In November 2014, Microsoft [released a community Edition of VS2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs), which is based on the Professional, supports Extensions and is free for home users.